# Get only property from object has only one property JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get only property js object. When I used `$('body')` it will return sometimes in object form and other times return only a property so how can I perform my task on that property. like..

```js
$('body').html();

// it will return in object
// [<body></body>]
// or sometime it will return only
// <body></body>
// if it will return in object so i got some error like.
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html is not a function

How can I make the return property consistent? Because I want to use this in some condition and I can't use it like this if I want to use it every time in object or only one property.

If it returns in object I want to use `eq()` but I don't know when it return in object form and when it return only property then how can I use `eq()` because is not use with only property.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sometime` means nothing in code. If there is another code that defined `$` (which probably what is happen), you can replace the jQuery `$` function with something like `$j`.

```
var $j = jQuery;
```

That's how you can be sure that a `jQuery` object will return, then you can use `eq` without worry.

For example:

```
$j('your_selector').eq(0);
```

**Live example**

```js
var $j = jQuery;

console.log($j('div').eq(0).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Test Text</div>
```

Comment: i was try this, but i can't use eq() everytime ,because i don't know when it return multiple selector or single. if it return more than one element so can't use other element.

Comment: `eq()` is an example. My point is that now `$j` replace the `$` so you shouldn't worry if any other library use `$` as variable. As I understood it's your problem. Isn't?